# foreach statements c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, foreach

I need some help with a for each statement, basically what happens is when a user edits a value within a cell, my foreach will apply this to all cells within the datagrid and change the value of them all, i need my foreach statement to work by iterating through the datagrid but only change the selected row that has been edited, but at the minute it seems to be updating the count on all rows, this should be only the current row

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDetials.Rows) //loop through each of the results
            {
                string scrapDate, scrapShift, PartCode;
                scrapDate = dtpInspectionDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                scrapShift = cbShift.Text;

                PartCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                //define each of the counts
                int qtyInspCount = SQLMethods.CountQtyInspTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode);
                int scrapCount = SQLMethods.CountScrapReworkTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode, "S");
                int reworkCount = SQLMethods.CountScrapReworkTotal(scrapDate, scrapShift, area, PartCode, "R");

                //populate each of the counts cells
                row.Cells[2].Value = 0;
                row.Cells[5].Value = qtyInspCount;
                row.Cells[3].Value = scrapCount;
                row.Cells[4].Value = reworkCount;
            }
```

Comment: Why have a `foreach`? You can get the edited cell directly.

Comment: Then why do you need to iterate through them all? Simply get the edited row index.

Comment: I don't understand your question, why loop through *all* the rows if you only want to change one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change only the current row.
Then you should avoid a lengthy loop on the whole datagrid rows collection.

There is the [CurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx) property just for this.

```
if(dgvDetials.CurrentRow != null)
{
    // Reference the current row 
    DataGridViewRow row = dgvDetials.CurrentRow;

    PartCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
    .....
    row.Cells[2].Value = 0; 
    row.Cells[5].Value = qtyInspCount; 
    row.Cells[3].Value = scrapCount; 
    row.Cells[4].Value = reworkCount; 
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event or get the selected GridViewRow.

```
GridViewRow datRow = SomeGridView.SelectedRow;
```